# TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined even though I can print it in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi everyone and thank you for taking the time to read my question and for the help!

Just finished a course in Web Programming and went on to making my first application. Everything was going fine till I kept getting this error coming up:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

What I'm trying to do is build a timesheet makeshift project. Using MongoDB, Node.js etc. The models work fine and the associations between two models (Timesheet and Times) work find saving etc.

The area in which the error keeps popping up is in this function:

```
function d(day, obj, timesheet) {
  var newDate;
  var timesheetParams = {
    weekNumber: moment().week(),
    year: moment().year(),
    employee: obj.employee
  };

  Timesheet.create(timesheetParams, function(err, newTimesheet) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {

      for (var num = 0; num < 7; num++) {
        // sets the date from the start of the week.
        newDate = moment().startOf('week').weekday(num).toDate();

        if (day[num].start[num] === '') {
          console.log(day[num].start[num]);
          Times.create(timesheet.timesheet, function(err, newTimes) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
              newTimes.date = newDate;
              newTimes.start = "OFF";
              newTimes.end = "OFF";
              newTimes.save();
              console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimes);
              newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
            }
          });

        } else {
          Times.create(timesheet.timesheet, function(err, newTimes) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
              newTimes.date = newDate;
              // ERROR HERE
              console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimes);
              newTimes.start = day[num].start[num];
              newTimes.end = day[num].end[num];
              newTimes.save();
              console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimes);
              newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
            }

          });
        }

        newTimesheet.save();
        //console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimesheet.times[num].start[num]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is what is being passed into the function:

d(times, {employee: foundEmployee}, {timesheet: req.body.timesheet});

Times being an array, and two objects that have the right info.

But for some reason in the function where I have the //ERROR HERE is where is getting caught and I've been trying a few things with it but nothing is working for me.

I know the function code looks really messy, I write it till it works then clean it up to make it better. So hope it isn't to jumbled.

Thanks again for any help! I really appreciate it!!

EDIT///

```
Timesheet.create(timesheetParams, function(err, newTimesheet) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        for(var num = 0; num <= 6; num++){
                // sets the date from the start of the week.
            newDate = moment().startOf('week').weekday(num).toDate();

            if(day[num].start[num] === ''){
                console.log(day[num].start[num]);
                Times.create(timesheet.timesheet, function(err, newTimes, day) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        // PRINTING OUT DAY
                        console.log("Day Printed: " + day);
                        newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
                        newTimes.date = newDate;
                        newTimes.start = "OFF";
                        newTimes.end = "OFF";
                        newTimes.save();
                        console.log("Without numbers being put in" + JSON.stringify(newTimes))
                        console.log("TESTER TIMES WITHOUT NUMBERS: " + newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.save();
                    }
                });

            } else { 
                Times.create(timesheet.timesheet, function(err, newTimes, day) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
                        newTimes.date = newDate;
                        // ERROR HERE
                        console.log("Day Printed: " + day);
                        newTimes.start = day[num].start[num];
                        newTimes.end = day[num].end[num];
                        newTimes.save();
                        console.log("With numbers being put in: " + JSON.stringify(newTimes))
                        console.log("TESTER TIMES WITH NUMBERS: " + newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.save();
                    }

                }); 
            }


            //console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimesheet.times[num].start[num]);
        }
    }
});
```

The print outs I get when I put no inputs in is:

```
Day Printed: undefined
Without numbers being put in{"date":"2016-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","__v":0,"start":"OFF","end":"OFF","_id":"56fa839af0d2dbe40310fa00","timesheet":{"id":"56fa839af0d2dbe40310f9ff"}}

TESTER TIMES WITHOUT NUMBERS: { timesheet: { id: 56fa839af0d2dbe40310f9ff },
_id: 56fa839af0d2dbe40310fa00,
end: 'OFF',
start: 'OFF',
__v: 0,
date: Sat Apr 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) }
```

Keeps saying day is undefined ><.

When i put in inputs then of time I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined

Thanks again guys!

EDIT 2//

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var timesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    timesheet: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Timesheet"
        }
    },

    date: Date,
    start: String,
    end: String
}
```

);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Times", timesSchema);

Comment: Can you do a **console.log(JSON.stringify(newTimes))** and add the result to your question please?

Comment: No problem :). To moments! Thank you.

Comment: `day` is not defined in the callback function `function(err, newTimes)`. You shouls pass it in as an argument

Comment: Would I need to put the day in the callback? I thought since the day was within the scope of the whole function it would of seen it. Does that need to happen within every callback to see the data in it?

Comment: @SmiffyKmc can you also do a console.log(day) and see what you get near the //ERROR HERE?

Comment: @KФ Yeah no problem, just trying to make it look clear so not wasting your time :). Thanks guys!